# Iptables Not Blocking User

Tags: iptables

iptables seems to not want to block a user.

I'm using a remastered 10.04 live and Firestarter as a firewall.  I've made no fundamental changes to the distro, except to update, upgrade and added this iptable line for my admin user dev:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner dev -j DROP
```

I've allowed dev, my admin, to use Firefox as another user:

gksudo -u browserUser /usr/bin/firefox

*Note: The purpose of this is stop opening up browser scripts to the admin account, and instead use a clean account with no privs as a proxy.*

Now, I test to see if iptables is blocking in case admin accidentally tried to connect without using another user.  So I try Midori browser directly:

```
/usr/bin/midori
```

Midori launches, and connects to the internet.  I'm puzzled.  My iptables entry doesn't seem to work.

I added the same line I remastered with:

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p all -m owner --uid-owner dev -j DROP
```

I still am not blocked.  So, I try reseting the tables:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

I get output:

```
 * Reconfiguring network interfaces...
Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0.
```

I try connecting again with Midori browser, and my iptable rule is still ignored.

What's happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order of your rules in iptables is critical. If a packet matches an earlier rule, there is no further processing.

You are appending ( -A ) your rules to the end of the OUTPUT chain, so, my guess is the packets are accepted by an earlier rule.

If you put the rule first, with `-I OUTPUT 1`, it will work.

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p all -m owner --uid-owner dev -j DROP
```

Your user case is more complex as you are using 2 tools, firestarter and iptables, to manage your firewall rules. I suggest you use one or the other, but not both.

If you would like to see your rule set, use

```
sudo iptables -L -v -n
```

And if you want to use iptables to manage your firewall see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

Comment: Thanks. I did notice after some testing firestarter and ufw both wiped the iptable slate clean and started with their own config.  I'm going to have to go with iptables, because I need to block a user specifically per reason in my question.  It doesn't appear ufw or firestarter supports this.

Comment: I'm just getting started with iptables.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: You are most welcome. Post back with questions.

Comment: I'm learning the order you issue iptables commands are very important.  I want to call these two commands:    `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`
    `iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`  Which should I put first?  I'm concerned the first may except everything, but instead I'd like to make sure only what I start can create connections on port 80.  Does it matter?  Should I just leave out the first one?

Comment: The order of those 2 rules is not going to matter.

Comment: I was thinking maybe the first would allow anyone trying to connect to port 80.  Should I drop the first line if I only want to allow connections I have established?

Comment: That is what the first line does. You need the rule if you want to accept all traffic on port 80 (if you are running a http server), although If that is the case I would allow NEW traffic to port 80 first, then your established,related rule.